# Odoo, actualizar vista de datos construidos a través de una función

Tags: odoo

espero puedan ayudarme con un problema que tengo. Estoy haciendo un proyecto de curso en Odoo 16 y tengo una vista en la que muestro datos que construyo en una función de un modelo transitorio. La vista se muestra bien con los datos cuando lo ejecuto desde el menú, pero si le doy F5 desde ahí misma me da error.
Esta es la definición del botón que me pone datos en el modelo

```
<record model="ir.actions.server" id="application_pendings_function">
    <field name="name">application_pendings</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_application_pendings"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">action = model.get_data_for_tree_view()</field>
</record>
```

Y esta es la función que se ejecuta, donde cargo todas las solicitudes pendiente de los clientes y las compañías y actualizo los datos del modelo con ellas

```
def get_data_for_tree_view(self):
    records = self.search([])
    records.unlink()

    aplications_client = self.env['application.client'].search([('status', '=', 'pending')])
    aplications_company = self.env['application.company'].search([('status', '=', 'pending')])

    data = []
    for rec in aplications_client:
        data.append({
            'type_app': 'Application client',
            'name': rec.name,
        })
    for rec in aplications_company:
        data.append({
            'type_app': 'Application company',
            'name': rec.name,
        })

    self.create(data)
    action = {
        'name': 'Application Pendings',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'view_type': 'tree',
        'res_model': self._name,
        'target': 'current',
        'res_id': self.env.ref('proyecto_curso.application_pendings_view_tree').id,
    }
    return action
```

Esta es la vista de ese modelo transitorio

```
<record id="application_pendings_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">application_pendings_view_tree</field>
    <field name="model">application.pendings</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree create="false" edit="false" delete="false">
            <field name="type_app"/>
            <field name="name"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Desde el menú funciona bien, pero si doy F5 da el siguiente error, esta es la captura del mismo:

[image: Captura de patalla del error]

Este es el modelo completo:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class ApplicationPendings(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'application.pendings'
    _description = 'Application Pendings TransientModel'

    name = fields.Char(string='Application Type')
    type_app = fields.Char(string='Application Name')
    
    def get_data_for_tree_view(self):
        records = self.search([])
        records.unlink()

        aplications_client = self.env['application.client'].search([('status', '=', 'pending')])
        aplications_company = self.env['application.company'].search([('status', '=', 'pending')])

        data = []
        for rec in aplications_client:
            data.append({
                'type_app': 'Application client',
                'name': rec.name,
            })
        for rec in aplications_company:
            data.append({
                'type_app': 'Application company',
                'name': rec.name,
            })

        self.create(data)
        action = {
            'name': 'Application Pendings',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'view_type': 'tree',
            'res_model': self._name,
            'target': 'current',
            'res_id': self.env.ref('proyecto_curso.application_pendings_view_tree').id,
        }
        return action
```

Alguien me puede ayudar y decirme porque si lo ejecuto desde el menú definido funciona bien pero al dar F5 da ese error. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. No muestras el tipo de modelo que estas usando. Me supongo que no estas usando un `TransientModel`. No me he topado con estos errores, pero posiblemente sea por que cuando recargas los datos que generaste dejan de existir. Los `TransientModel` viven de manera temporal hasque odoo internamente elimina los datos. Si publicas tu modelo será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias @Legna si es un TransientModel, ya edité la pregunta y le agregué el modelo completo, espero realmente puedas ayudarme, por el momento lo que hice fue cambiar 'target': 'current', por 'new' para que no cambiara de vista y si le doy F5 se quedara en la actual y esto saliera a modo de ventana, por el momento voy resolviendo con ello

Answer (score 0):

Hay algo extraño en odoo y es que en realidad la vista "tree" no se llama "tree", si no "list". Entonces la estructura de tu `action`, en el campo `view_type` y `view_mode` debe de decir `list`.

```py
def get_data_for_tree_view(self):
       #... más codigo...
        action = {
            'name': 'Application Pendings',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',

            # Este es el purrum
            'view_mode': 'list',
            'view_type': 'list',


            'res_model': self._name,
            'target': 'current',
            'res_id': self.env.ref('proyecto_curso.application_pendings_view_tree').id,
        }
        return action
```

## Mi teoría.

Te estaras preguntado por que la primera vez si funciona. Bueno, le estás pasando una vista directa con el `id` en el campo `res_id`, de manera que "ignora" ambos campos y te abre la lista, el problema es que cuando recargas, lo que se queda en memoria no es el id, si no el `view_mode` y el `view_type`, que están mal.

Comment: Le puse 'list', pero igual da el mismo error al dar F5, lo que hice fue cambiar 'target': 'current', por 'new', para que lo sacara como una ventana sin salir de la vista actual